# AttributeError: module 'my_package' has no attribute 'member', but I can see 'my_package.member' in site_packages

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I have a Poetry package and a consuming Python application.

The Poetry package has this in its `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-package"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = [...]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [
    { include = "my_package/__init__.py", from = "." },
    { include = "my_package/transmitter/*", from = "." },
]
```

I am installing this as a git dependency in the consuming app, which has this requirement in its `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
my-package = { git = "git@github.com:example/my-company-my-package.git", branch = "my-feature-branch"}
```

I'm installing all deps using `poetry install`. After doing so, I can see two directories appear under `site_packages` in PyCharm (and under the virtual poetry environment):

- `my_package`
- `my_package-0.1.0.dist-info`

The former contains a `transmitter` package, which of course contains an `__init__.py`, as well as a `udp_transmitter.py` module. `__init__.py` contains `from .udp_transmitter import *`

`udp_transmitter.py` contains a `UDPTransmitter` class.

So, I would expect this import to work inside the consuming application:

`from my_package.transmitter import UDPTransmitter`

However, when running the code, I get:

`AttributeError: module 'my_package' has no attribute 'transmitter'`

But I can clearly see inside `site_packages` that there is a package named `my_package`, which contains a `transmitter` package, which in turn exports everything from a `udp_transmitter.py` module.

In summary, I have a Poetry package that, when installed as a (dev) dependency of another project, results in this:

```
.
└── site_packages/
    ├── my_package/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── transmitter/
    │       ├── __init__.py (imports * from udp_transmitter.py)
    │       └── udp_transmitter.py
    └── my_package-0.1.0.dist-info/
        ├── direct_url.json
        ├── INSTALLER
        ├── METADATA
        ├── RECORD
        └── WHEEL
```

But I get an AttributeError if I try to import `my_package.transmitter`.

What could cause this?

**EDIT**

Importing this way works:
`from my_package.transmitter.udp_transmitter import UDPTransmitter`